# Who am I if I'm legendary?

Tags: riddle

> I'm legendary
>
> People are looking for me
>
> Oh look! At Times Square!
>
> There I am! Looking down at you
>
> I am powerful
>
> I am an advanced version of the first half of my name
>
> But I killed my first version
>
> I am uncontrollable
>
> I am too powerful
>
> I am the only evil of my type
>
> Yet I am now inside a game
>
> being toyed with, being wanted.

**Hint:**

> Red has me

Comment: Please try to refrain from giving direct clues in your riddles. This way it's just a description instead of a riddle, making it very easy to solve. See [this page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/riddle/info) for more information and some tips about creating riddles.

Comment: You are Barney Stinson, or rather, Neil Patrick Harris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are :

> [Mewtwo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), the 150th Pokémon.

I'm legendary

> Indeed, there's only one Mewtwo.

People are looking for me

> Who would decline having him?

Oh look! At Times Square!

> He appears here in the teaser for Pokémon Go!

There I am! Looking down at you

> [image]

I am powerful

> Well, he is.

I am an advanced version of the first half of my name

> Referring to [Mew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mew_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), of course.

But I killed my first version

> [NOOOOOOOO!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGDn0K-MEBI)

I am uncontrollable

> A Pokémon has no trainer

I am too powerful

> Obviously! Please nerf!

I am the only evil of my type

> Indeed, he is.

Yet I am now inside a game
being toyed with, being wanted.

> [Ah, the memories...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red_and_Blue)

Comment: I'm going to retire on making riddles, I'm making them too easy

Comment: @AbAppletic you just posted 2 riddles on a row. you should elaborate it more. people spend days making a riddle that makes people spend hours solving. :/

Comment: @lois6b you're right, I should stop and spend some time on a hard one

Comment: @AbAppletic Yes, this was easy. Still, I enjoyed building this answer :)

Comment: *mewt**w**o Typo